# How to Add a Custom Function That Can Be Chained with the Auth() Function?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authentication, laravel-helper

As stated in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers), the `auth()` function can be used instead of the `Auth` facade, returns an authenticator instance and can be used like this:

```php
auth()->check() 
auth()->guest()
auth()->id() 
auth()->user()
```

As you can see - I can chain `->check()` or `->guest()` or `->id()` or `->user()`.

Is it possible to add a new custom function that can be also chaned? For example, `somethingNew()` that can be used like this:

```
auth()->somethingNew() // returns boolean
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `auth` helper simply returns the instance of the [guard](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Contracts/Auth/Guard.html) being used. You can implement [custom guards](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#adding-custom-guards) which would expose your `somethingNew` method.

Configure the application to use your new guard in [config/app.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/auth.php) and enjoy calling `auth()->somethingNew()`.